# creating a list of path in f#

Tags: graph, f#, primitive

(This is probably a classic, but I wonder how to best express it)

I start on the left, at some date. 
For some assets I can compute returns from the starting date to some future date.
From that future date, I can move further in time recursively.

I would like to generate all the path that go as far as possible to right, but that stops before some target date.

Here is my code. 'a is an asset, and (DateTime*DateTime) are 2 times for which I have a quote for the said underlying.

```
  member this.getPaths dtstart dtend : Set<('a*(DateTime*DateTime)) list>=
     let rec getPaths dtstart dtend (pastpath:List<'a*(DateTime*DateTime)>) : seq<('a*(DateTime*DateTime)) list>=
        let udls = this.getUnderlyingsQuotingAt dtstart
        let onestep = seq { for udl in udls do
                                let qt = this.QuoteNextAfterSrict udl dtstart 
                                if qt.IsNone || (qt.Value |> fst > dtend) then
                                   yield pastpath |> List.rev  
                                else
                                   let nextdate = qt.Value |> fst 
                                   yield! (getPaths nextdate dtend  ((udl, (dtstart, nextdate))::pastpath) )  } 
        onestep
     getPaths dtstart dtend  List.empty |> Set.ofSeq
```

Since I use yield!, I will collect a new path for each failure in the end.
So, I have to de-duplicate my sequence in the end.
My question is : are there some better way to find complete path, without de-duplication ?

I could make a second pass or add a List argument, but is there some "pure" way to do this in one go ?

*update*

I think I got the whole approach wrong with many useless inner loops.
probably vectorizing the next available quotes would be useful. i will update the code after refactoring.

*update 2*

A first rewrite is the following which move the yield |> List.rev one level above, allowing for cutting unnecessary exploration.

```
  member this.getPaths dtstart dtend : Set<('a*(DateTime*DateTime)) list>=
     let count = ref  0

     printfn "computing path from %A to %A " dtstart dtend
     let rec getPaths dtstart dtend (pastpath:List<'a*(DateTime*DateTime)>)  : seq<('a*(DateTime*DateTime)) list>=
        let udls      = this.getUnderlyingsQuotingAt dtstart
        let udlquotes = udls |> Seq.map   (fun udl -> (udl , this.QuoteNextAfterSrict udl dtstart))
                                              |> Seq.filter (fun   (_, q) -> q.IsSome)
                                              |> Seq.map    (fun   (udl, q) -> (udl, q.Value))
                                              |> Seq.filter (fun   (_, q) -> fst q <= dtend  )

        let onestep = seq { if udlquotes.IsEmpty then
                                yield pastpath  |> List.rev  
                            else
                                for (udl, q) in udlquotes  do
                                      let nextdate =  (fst q)
                                      count := !count + 1
                                      if !count%1000 = 0 then printfn "!count  %A , path : %A " !count pastpath
                                      yield! (getPaths nextdate dtend  ((udl, (dtstart,  nextdate))::pastpath)   )
                       }
        onestep
     getPaths dtstart dtend  List.empty |> Set.ofSeq
```

Comment: I realize it's not answering your question but one thing you might do is use a type alias to make your code a bit easier to read.  You use 'a*(DateTime*DateTime) in at least two places. This may be a bit easier to read __type datespan<'a> = 'a*(DateTime*DateTime)__ and then use datespan in your set and your list.  As I say, I realize this isn't answering your question but it would make your code a bit easier to read.

Comment: you are totally right. thanks for your suggestion. I will add some comments about the code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand your algorithm, but I think that the general structure looks good. What do you mean by "de-duplication"? If you're referring to the `List.rev` call that is used at the end of the recursive processing, then that's quite common pattern (and I don't think there is a better way to do that).

Regarding the F# coding style, it is a bit disappointing that you cannot easily use pattern matching when analyzing the `qt` value (because the condition cannot be encoded using a built-in pattern). However, you can define a helper parameterized active pattern that matches when the input is greater than the parameter:

```
let inline (|MoreThan|_|) limit input = 
  if input > limit then Some input else None
```

Using the pattern, you can make the body of your `seq` a bit more readable:

```
let rec getPaths dtstart dtend pastpath = seq {
  let udls = this.getUnderlyingsQuotingAt dtstart 
  for udl in udls do 
    match this.QuoteNextAfterSrict udl dtstart with
    | None 
    | Some (MoreThan dtend _, _) ->
        yield pastpath |> List.rev   
    | Some (nextdate, _) ->
        let newpath = (udl, (dtstart, nextdate))::pastpath
        yield! getPaths nextdate dtend newpath }
```

Comment: For the duplication, let's imagine I have 10 underlyings, and all the tests in (qt.Value |> fst > dtend)  lead to a termination. I will have a sequence of 10 empty sequences. I will look into your suggestion which looks much more idiomatic. thanks.

Comment: @nicolas Ah, I'm starting to understand - so, basically, if `QuoteNextAfterStrict udl dtstart` retruns value that matches the first pattern (in my version) for any `udl` in `udls`, then you want to yield `pastpath |> List.rev` once, otherwise you want to yield it zero-times?

Comment: @nicolas If that's the case, I would probably run `QuoteNextAfterStrict` on all values in `udls` using `List.map` and then tested if all values match the first pattern - if yes, you can return `pastpath |> List.rev`. Then you could iterate over those that match the second pattern and yield recursively. You could split them into the two cases using `List.partition`.